# Add background image and border image to form

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a simple form based on jquery -

```
<center>
    <form id="form1">
    <div id="registerDiv" data-role="fieldcontain" >    
     <input type="button" value="Register" id="registerButton" data-inline="true"/>
    </div>
    </form>
  </center>
```

Id like to modify the form so that it has two background images, one background covers the button (number 1 in attachment - layout.png), the second is a background image that act as a border(number 2 in attachment - layout.png). What is the best method of achieving this ?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you're looking for is this:

```
#form1 { 
    background: url( /images/background1.jpg ) no-repeat;
}

#registerDiv {
    margin: 40px;
    background: url( /images/background2.jpg ) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just need a minor tweak, how can I amend the size of the left, top, right & bottom margins individually ?

Comment: kind of lazy of me asking that ;) -  margin-bottom: 5%; margin-top: 10%; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .outer {background:url(layout-outer.png);padding:12px}
  .inner {background:url(layout-inner.png);padding:12px}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <form id="form1">
    <div class="inner">
      <!-- other input items as necessary -->
      <input type="button" value="register" id="registerButton" data-inline="true" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The key part here is the amount of padding in '.outer'.  This is basically your border width.